# Regex to replace all spaces in the code block marker of markdown file

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I want to replace each group of spaces with a single comma in code block marker in every markdown file.

For example I have this code block:

````
```html   class1 class2
````

Note that above line have two group of spaces, one with 3 spaces, other with single space.

I want to replace it to:

````
```html,class1,class2
````

I have tried following command without success:

````sh
find src -type f -name "*.md" -exec sed -i s/^(?<=```)( )+/,/g {} +
````

Meaning: if a line contains ``` at the start then replace all spaces with comma.
But it doesn't work.

What is correct command should I use here?

Comment: You need to use `-E` to use metacharacters like `()+` and lookarounds isn't supported by `sed`. See also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/109046)

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67957653/3832970) work for you? Do you need more assistance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it (with GNU sed):

````
sed '/^```/ s/\s\+/,/g' your_file
````

The ways it's working is as follows:

- For lines beginning with three backticks... ```` /^```/ ````
- Replace all (`g` means global replacement) occurrences of one or more spaces
  (`\s` means space, `\+` means one or more) with a comma

Once you've confirmed it does what you want, just add the `-i` to do the
substitution in-place:

````
sed -i '/^```/ s/\s\+/,/g' your_file
````

Answer (score 2):

You can use

````sh
sed -E '/^```/ s/[[:space:]]+/,/g' file
````

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/ROtYHw)

*Details*:

- `-E` enables the POSIX ERE syntax
- ```` /^```/ ```` - if the line starts with ```` ``` ```` go on and execute the subsequent commands
- `s/[[:space:]]+/,/g` - replaces one or  more whitespaces with a single `,` char.

````sh
s='```html   class1 class2
html   class3 class4'
sed -E '/^```/ s/[[:space:]]+/,/g' <<< "$s"
````

Output:

````sh
```html,class1,class2
html   class3 class4
````

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

````
$ awk -v OFS=',' '/^```/{$1=$1} 1' file
```html,class1,class2
````

If you want to do "inplace" editing (like you're doing with GNU sed for `sed -i`) then use GNU awk and make it ```` awk -i inplace -v OFS=',' '/^```/{$1=$1} 1' file ````